# Zend Framework: Conditional validation

Tags: zend-framework, forms, conditional-statements, validation, zend-validate

I need to set up some validation for a form field based on a value of another field.

For instance if profession is Doctor, then require specialty not to be blank ('') or none ('none').

```
$professionOptions = array(
        ''      => 'Choose Profession',
        'Dr.'   => 'Dr.',
        'zzz'   => 'zzz',
        'None'  => 'None');
 $this->validator->field('profession')->inArray(array_keys($professionOptions)) ->message('Invalid profession.');


 $specialtySelectOptions = array(
            ''      => 'Choose Specialty',
            'Heart' => 'Heart',
            'Lungs' => 'Lungs',
            'Feet'  => 'Feet',
            'Nose'  => 'Nose');
```

How do i make the following dependent on the profession?

```
$this->validator->field('specialty')->inArray(array_keys($specialtySelectOptions))
                                            ->message('Invalid salutation.');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can extend the isValid() method in your form class, e.g.

```
/**
 * @param array $data The data from the request to validate
 */
public function isValid($data)
{
    $this->checkSpecialityForProfession($data);
    return parent::isValid($data)
}

protected function checkSpecialityForProfession($data)
{
    if($data['profession'] === 'Dr.') {
        $validator = new Zend_Validate_InArray(array(
            'Heart',
            'Lungs',
            'Feet',
            'Nose',
            )
        );

        $this->getElement('specialty')->addValidator($validator);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually go this way

```
$f = new My_Form();

if($f->isValid($_POST)) {
  // extra validation
  if($f->getValue('profession') === 'Dr.') {
    $specialty = $f->getValue('specialty');
    if($specialty === '' || $specialty === 'none') {
      $f->markAsError();
      $f->specialty->addError('error_msg');
    }
  }

  if(!$f->isErrors()) {
    $f->save();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This guy figured out a slick way via a custom validation class.
http://jeremykendall.net/2008/12/24/conditional-form-validation-with-zend_form/